# How we can setup pattern for logback-access.xml inside MDC and make use of MDC value inside <pattern></pattern>

Tags: logging, logback, mdc

So, I am trying to achieve one scenario. I want to define a customizable pattern for my logback-access.xml file or logabck.xml file. I am setting up log pattern value in MDC and try to make use of this pattern in  block.

I am facing then two scenarios:

- For logback-access.xml I am seeing parse error for that MDC variable.
- For logback.xml I am getting pattern value logged in console.
  So, If I am setting up value as:
  MDC.put("console_pattern", "%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%thread] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n");
  I should get a proper format log if I set pattern as:
  %X{console_pattern}

  Result I am getting in console should be a proper log statement, but I am getting `%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%thread] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n` in log response.

I want to setup pattern value in MDC and instead of hardcoding pattern I want to access through MDC format. That's my actual ask.

Can anyone please help in this. Thanks in advance.